# how can I get values from the table

Tags: abap

I concatenated values of select-options and a parameter. The condition of that query is based on the concatenated data. I can get all the data i need.

here's my code:

```
TABLES: bkpf.

SELECT-OPTIONS: s_belnr FOR bkpf-belnr NO-EXTENSION OBLIGATORY .
PARAMETERS: p_ghjahr LIKE bkpf-gjahr DEFAULT sy-datum(4) OBLIGATORY. "Fiscal

DATA: it_con TYPE TABLE OF BKPF,
      ls_con TYPE bkpf-AWKEY,
      lv_belnr   LIKE bkpf-belnr,
      IT TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF BKPF,
      WA TYPE BKPF.

IF s_belnr-high IS INITIAL.
  CONCATENATE s_belnr-low p_ghjahr INTO ls_con.
  APPEND ls_con TO it_con.
ELSE.  
  lv_belnr = s_belnr-low.
  WHILE lv_belnr LE s_belnr-high.
    CONCATENATE lv_belnr p_ghjahr INTO ls_con.
    APPEND ls_con TO it_con.
    ADD 1 TO lv_belnr.
    CALL FUNCTION 'CONVERSION_EXIT_ALPHA_INPUT'
      EXPORTING
        input  = lv_belnr
      IMPORTING
        output = lv_belnr.
  ENDWHILE.
ENDIF.
LOOP AT it_concats INTO ls_concats.
  SELECT BELNR
    FROM BKPF 
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE IT 
    FOR ALL ENTRIES IN IT_CONCATS 
    WHERE AWKEY EQ IT_CONCATS-AWKEY.
ENDLOOP.

LOOP AT IT INTO WA.
  WRITE: / WA-BELNR.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I can't get the belnr from bkpf using the concatenated value as condition in the select query. how can I get the belnr using that concatenated value?

Comment: 1. Why don't you condition the document number directly? (WHERE belnr IN s_belnr) 2. Can you describe your logic, what you want to achieve? s_belnr-high will be always empty in your code.

Comment: i need to get the belnr from bkpf using its awkey which is the concatenated belnr and fiscal date from rbkp.

Comment: So, you want to select vendor invoice in FI, which are created from MM invoices? The question is, what document number you have? Because the MM invoice number won't necessary the same like the FI invoice number (it can be, but it depends on, whether your system uses the correponding user exit (there is an OSS Note about that)). If you have the MM invoice number, than go like: BKPF-AWTYP = 'RMRP' AND BKPF-AWKEY = RBKP-BELNR + RBKP-GJAHR

Comment: Please format your code, it's all in one line !

Comment: Your code has a lot of flaws... Why the LOOP if you are using FOR ALL ENTRIES?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring (because your question is too vague), the type of document you are looking for, I'll suggest something like
(WARNING, I do NOT provide full answers, just code snipets who you must tune to make it work; if someone wants to improve my answer, feel free to do it, and I'll gladly will vote the new one as the good one... if it is)

```
data: awkey_range type range of bkpf-awkey,
      awkey_line like  line of awkey_range.

* Fill the awkey_range with something like
awkey_line-sign = 'I'.
awkey_line-option = 'EQ'.
* loop at bkpf_table into bkpf_line.
*   concatenate bkpf_line-belnr bkpf_line-ghjahr into awkey_line-low.
*   append awkey_line to awkey_range.
* endloop.

* And then a single SQL
select *
  from bkpf
  into table IT "Ouch, what a name
  where awkey in awkey_range.
```

And it should work, if I'm not missing something.